# How to append all elements of a certain class to the DOM

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I'd like to append all elements of the class 'active_element' to the document.body

How do I achieve this:

```
var element1 = document.createElement('div');
element1.classList.add('active_element');

var element2 = document.createElement('div');
element2.classList.add('active_element');

document.body.appendChild(element1);
document.body.appendChild(element2);
```

With a loop:

```
var element1 = document.createElement('div');
element1.classList.add('active_element');

var element2 = document.createElement('div');
element2.classList.add('active_element');

var active_elements = document.getElementsByClassName('active_element');
for (i=0; i<active_elements.length; i++) {
    document.documentElement.appendChild(active_elements[i]);
} // doesn't seem to work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find the elements with `document.getElementsByClassName()` until after they're added to the DOM.

Just use a loop to add them to the DOM, instead of assigning them to variables.

```
const divCount = 2;
for (i = 0; i < divCount; i++) {
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.classList.add('active_element');
    document.documentElement.appendChild(element);
}
```

If you need to create the DIVs at a separate time from when you append them, you could put them into an array.

```
active_elements = [];
var element1 = document.createElement('div');
element1.classList.add('active_element');
active_elements.push(element1);

var element2 = document.createElement('div');
element2.classList.add('active_element');
active_elements.push(element2);
```

Then later loop through the array.

```
active_elements.forEach(e => document.documentElement.appendChild(e));
```

Comment: If the OP has the option for delaying the creation of `divs` till final `appendChild` - Then this is a better answer

Answer (score 0):

`element1` and `element2` are not part of the document yet.

If you don't have an option for delaying the creation of `div`s till final `appendChild`, then try the following approach.

Append these two in a dummy `div` first

```
var containerDiv = document.createElement('div');
var element1 = document.createElement('div');
element1.classList.add('active_element');
var element2 = document.createElement('div');
element2.classList.add('active_element');
containerDiv.appendChild(element1);
containerDiv.appendChild(element2);
```

Now you can do `querySelector` on the `containerDiv` instead of `document`

```
//var active_elements = containerDiv.querySelectorAll('.active_element'); //you can use this as well.
var active_elements = containerDiv.getElementsByClassName('active_element');
for (i=0; i<active_elements.length; i++) 
{
    document.documentElement.appendChild(active_elements[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I sugest you to add all your elements to a documentFragment container.

After that you should query that container and get all your elements.

After that, just add your elements to the document.body container.

```
for (i=0; i<active_elements.length;i++){document.body.appendChild(active_elements[i]);}
```